# Make the tick in the Badges page clickable

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, help-center

I often miss cross-link from [the main Badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) to my list of awarded badges, especially to check which of my Q&A are "Nice".

Therefore I suggest that the **green tick** (see picture) next to the badges you have received could **link** to the [appropriate badge page on your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question?userid=189976).

> [image: Tick near the badge]

This is obviously useful especially for multi-award badges, but it can work for all of them, if one was interested in when they got that one. As well, the helper text, which now says "you've earned this badge" could say:

- either "you've earned this badge 5 times" (for multi-award badges)
- or "you've earned this badge 2 months ago" (for single-award badges)

Answer (score 3):

A while ago, I wrote the userscript [You've Earned This Badge, but when and where?](https://stackapps.com/q/7818/34061) which does exactly this:

> This userscript turns the checkmarks in the badge list (which indicate you've earned a
> specific badge) to links to your *personal* badge page, where you can see when and where
> you earned the badge.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

You can install the userscript with
[this direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/you-earned-this-badge/you-earned-this-badge.user.js).

I've searched high and low where I got the inspiration from; perhaps it was this feature request, but I can't remember it.